# w2008r2 DCPROMO for single label domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

- I have 2 Domain Controllers in my company.
- DC1 Primary is W2008 R2 [added recently],
- DC2 is W2003-R2 , 
  Its a single label domain named `ABC`

Yes I know that Microsoft recommends to use at least 2 or more name parts but this is old network running hundreds of workstation & servers since long & AD 2008 is introduced recently. W2003 base DC is still functioning as secondary/backup dc along with WDS. As AD design, users sometimes login to DC1 and sometimes to DC2 fine all working good.

Now as a part of disaster recovery plan , I have to restore the DC in test lab. I installed windows 2008 R2 in isolated VM, and started DCPROMO , but getting error 'single label domain' on name the domain section as MS KB states that

```
Windows Server 2008 R2 DCPROMO prevents the creation of new Active Directory domains with single-label DNS names.
```

How can I overcome this issue? How I will restore AD in case of real disaster ? any recommendation what path to follow?

Answer (score 3):

Why are you creating a new domain (dcpromo)?  All you need to do is restore DC system state and the domain will exist.

Comment: ok, to restore DC from backup (in fresh w2008) i dont need to run the dcpromo first? just restore directly?

Comment: correct; just restore.
If your backup software supports "bare metal recovery" you might not even need to install Windows first.